# Access objects within a Consumer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am working on a project that consumes messages using `MassTransit` and `RabbitMQ` in `C#`

I'm building a prototype and right now the consumer project is a console application.  Within the Main `program.cs` class, I connect to the bus and subscribe to accept messages from the publisher like this:

```
var bus = BusInitializer.CreateBus("Subscriber", x =>
            {
                x.Subscribe(subs =>
                {
                    subs.Consumer<UpdatedInformation>().Permanent();
                });
            });
```

For reference, here's the `CreateBus()` method:

```
public static IServiceBus CreateBus(string queueName, Action<ServiceBusConfigurator> moreInitialization)
{
    var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
    {
        x.UseRabbitMq();
        x.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/test" + queueName);
        moreInitialization(x);
    });

    return bus;
}
```

And here is an example of one of the consumer classes:

```
class UpdatedInformationConsumer : Consumes<UpdatedInformation>.Context
{

    public void Consume(IConsumeContext<UpdatedInformation> message)
    {
        Console.Write("\nMessage: " + message.Message);
        Console.Write("\nPROCESSED: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the main class of the subscriber, I also initialize services and other configurations.  What I need to do is be able to access those services/objects in my consumer classes as I don't want to initialize new ones every time a message is received in consumed.

This should be relatively easy, but I'm stumped since I'm not actually creating instances of my consumer classes.

Comment: Have you considered singleton pattern for your initialized services and configurations? http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: @MikeHixson Of course, I was completely over thinking it and overlooked the easiest solution!  If you want to add some more information and make it an answer I'll mark it as accepted to help anyone in the future with a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than put a bunch of singletons in your service, which leads to a bunch of static methods and so forth, you can specify a consumer factory with your subscription that passes those dependencies to your consumer. You can also use any of the supported containers (or even your own) to resolve those dependencies.

```
x.Subscribe<UpdatedInformationConsumer>(() => 
    new UpdatedInformationConsumer(dependency1, dependency2, etc));
```

A new instance of the consumer will be created for each message receiving, so object lifecycles can also be managed in this way.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I was having issues when 2 threads were trying to initialize the Singleton due to having to open a file.  This is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes it does, you can resolve your consumer from the container. There are integrations for many containers that will begin/end a lifetime scope for each message as well. Like MassTransit.Autofac.