# MessageBus: wait when processing is done and send ACK to requestor

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit

We work with external TCP/IP interfaces and one of the requirements is to keep connection open, wait when processing is done and send ACK with the results back.

What would be best approach to achieve that assuming we want to use MessageBus (masstransit/nservicebus) for communication with processing module and tracing message states: received, processing, succeeded, failed?

Specifically, when message arrives to handler/consumer, how it will know about TCP/IP connection? Should I store it in some custom container and inject it to consumer?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the TCP/IP connection is used for monitoring the state of message processing in NServiceBus?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the connection open?

Comment: @HadiEskandari, when message comes from external interfaces it triggers certain action, like "create order". And it expects ACK about if order was created or failed over the _same_ opened TCP/IP connection. It doesn't support delayed follow-up response unfortunately. These interfaces were designed 30 years ago and we can't change them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer will know how to initiate and manage the TCP connection lifecycle.

When a message is received, the handler can invoke the code which performs some action based on the message data. Whether this involves displaying an green elephant on a screen somewhere or opening a port, making a call, and then processing the ACK, does not change how you handle the message.

The actual code which is responsible for performing the action could be packaged into something like a nuget package and exposed over some kind of generic interface if that makes you happier, but there is no contradiction with a component having a dual role as a message consumer and processor of that message.

> A new instance of the consumer will be created for each message
>   receiving. Also, in my case, consumer can’t initiate TCP/IP
>   connection, it has been already opened earlier (and stored somewhere
>   else) and consumer needs just have access to use it.

Sorry, I should have read your original question more closely.

There is a solution to shared access to a resource from NServiceBus, as documented [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/accessing-data).

```
public class SomeEventHandler : IHandleMessages<SomeEvent>
{
    private IMakeTcpCall _caller;

    public SomeEventHandler(IMakeTcpCalls caller)
    {
        _caller = caller;
    }

    public Task Handle(SomeEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // Use the caller 
        var ack = _caller.Call(message.SomeData);

        // Do something with ack
        ...

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You would ideally have a DI container which would manage the lifecycle of the *IMakeTcpCall* instance as a singleton (though this might get weird in high volume scenarios), so that you can re-use the open TCP channel.

Eg, in [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor):

```
Component.For<IMakeTcpCalls>().ImplementedBy<MyThreadsafeTcpCaller>().LifestyleSingleton();
```

Castle Windsor [integrates](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor) with NServiceBus

Comment: A new instance of the consumer will be created for each message receiving. Also, in my case, consumer can’t initiate TCP/IP connection, it has been already opened earlier (and stored somewhere else) and consumer needs just have access to use it. Sounds like this information should be injected into consumer ([as suggested by Chris Patterson here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328336/2827454)).

Comment: thanks, it makes sense. In my case I will have to use MassTransit and Autofac. I'm sure similar functionality is supported there.